# Angular Ngrx - How to get differents call looping an array?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

In this effect I would to take the action payload that contains an object like this

```
 {
     firms: [{ id: 1, firmName: 'string', roles: ['admin', 'supadmin', 'user'] }],
     type: "loadFolder",
     userId: 1
 };
```

For each strings inside roles array, and with userId inside the action payload, I have to do an httpCall passing its as parameter and after that I need to populate three differents lists based on the roles (userList, adminLIst, supadminList). I can't find a solution for doing it.

```
loadFolder$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.action$.pipe(
  ofType(SidebarAction.loadFirmSuccess),
  switchMap(action => {

    let roles: Array < string > = [];
    let supadminlist = [];
    let adminList = [];
    let userList = [];

    action.firms.map(
      firm => {
        firm.roles.map((role: string) => {
          roles.push(role);
        });
      }
    );
    
    roles.forEach(role => {
      this.sidebarService.getFolders(action.userId, role).subscribe(res => {
          switch (role) {
            case ('supadmin'):
              supadminlist = res;
              break;
            case ('admin'):
              adminList = res;
              break;
            case ('user'):
              userList = res;
          }
        });
    });

    return sidebarAction.loadFoldersSuccess({supadmin, adminList, userList});
      
  }),
);
});
```

I tried in this way...I'm not sure how to implement this and this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You returning `loadFoldersSuccess` action BEFORE the http-calls are done. Use `forkJoin` to make your http calls then return `loadFoldersSuccess`.

```
const a = {}
roles.forEach(role => {
  a[role] = this.sidebarService.getFolders(action.userId, role)
});

return forkJoin(a).pipe(map(x => {
    return sidebarAction.loadFoldersSuccess(x);
}));
```